# two codes Theoreticaly same but practicaly works different...how is it possible

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-dl

**getaudio.php** *version 1*

```
<?php
    $youtubeUrl =  $_GET['url'];
    $content = shell_exec("youtube-dl -j $youtubeUrl "); 
    $meta=json_decode($content);  
    $file= $meta->{'_filename'};
    $fileWithoutExtension = explode(".",$file)[0];
    $extension = ".m4a";
    $file = $fileWithoutExtension . $extension;   

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"" );
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

    passthru("youtube-dl -f 140 -o - $youtubeUrl");     
?>
```

**getaudio.php** *version 2*

```
<?php
    $youtubeUrl =  $_GET['url'];
    $file = shell_exec("youtube-dl -f 140 --get-filename $youtubeUrl "); 

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"" );
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

    passthru("youtube-dl -f 140 -o - $youtubeUrl");
?>
```

---

if 
**url** = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvYtKY-UMxA then we get **$file** =
Deewana Kar Raha Hai Full Song 1080p HD Raaz 3 2012   YouTube-bvYtKY-UMxA.m4a

my question is **getaudio.php version 1** is working fine but **getaudio.php version 2** isn't....

**getaudio.php version 2** is downloading but the file is coruppted....

---

when **$file** is same for both php files then how is it possible that the second one is not working

---

HINT: download **youtube-dl.exe**(for windows) & **place** it with the **two php** files & run in localhost

Comment: what is your print_r($file) in version 1 and version 2 of your script?

Comment: the first line of your version version 2 is <?php  ?

Comment: your file getaudio version 2 only have the code that you posted? The first line of the file is <?php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73209/discussion-between-adrian-cid-almaguer-and-akash-chauhan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$youtubeUrl =  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvYtKY-UMxA";
$content = shell_exec("youtube-dl -j $youtubeUrl "); 
$meta=json_decode($content);  
$file= $meta->{'_filename'};
$fileWithoutExtension = explode(".",$file)[0];
$extension = ".m4a";

$file1 = $fileWithoutExtension . $extension;   

$file2 = shell_exec("youtube-dl -f 140 --get-filename $youtubeUrl ");

echo $file1,"NO SPACE HERE"; 
echo "<br>";    
 // have extra space at the end 
echo $file2,"SPACE HERE";        

echo "<br>"; 
echo "length of \$file1 is :".strlen($file1);  // 77
echo "<br>"; 
echo "length of \$file2 is :".strlen($file2);  // 78
```

?>

OUTPUT

> Deewana Kar Raha Hai Full Song 1080p HD Raaz 3 2012
>   YouTube-bvYtKY-UMxA.m4a---NO SPACE HERE
>
> Deewana Kar Raha Hai Full Song 1080p HD Raaz 3 2012
>   YouTube-bvYtKY-UMxA.m4a ---SPACE HERE
>
> length of $file1 is :77
>
> length of $file2 is :78

See that there is no whitespace after **.m4a** for *$file1* but for *$file2* there is a whitespace after **.m4a**.

that makes them two different string

SOLUTION:
Use trim() function on $file in **getaudio.php version 2**

```
$file = trim($file);
```